# what kind of keyboard layout can type ISO 8859-1 Characters?

Tags: internationalization, character-encoding, foreign-keys, iso-8859-1

what kind of keyboard layout can type ISO 8859-1 Characters?

Example of what needs to be typed are:-

Ánam àbìa èbèa Ógbuá

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all: Keyboard layouts and character sets are not directly tied to each other. If I type `Ü` on my keyboard while in a UTF-8 application, the resulting character will be 
 a UTF-8 character. If I type it in a ISO-8859-1 application, it will be a character from that character set.

That said, there isn't a keyboard layout that covers *all* ISO-8859-1 characters; every country layout covers a part of them.

[Full list of characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

According to Wikipedia, ISO-8859-1 covers the following languages' special characters in full:

> Afrikaans, Albanian, Basque, Breton, Catalan, English (UK and US), Faroese, Galician, German, Icelandic, Irish, (new
>    - orthography), Italian, Kurdish (The
>     Kurdish Unified Alphabet), Latin
>      (basic classical orthography), Leonese,
>      Luxembourgish (basic classical
>      orthography), Norwegian (Bokmål and
>      Nynorsk), Occitan, Portuguese,
>      Rhaeto-Romanic, Scottish, Gaelic,
>      Spanish, Swahili, Swedish, Walloon

so you can safely assume that the keyboard layouts of those countries cover a *part* of ISO-8859-1.

Comment: @Pekka Thanks once again. I am developing an app but I want my users to type in their native language. Unfortunately our native languages are not listed but could make do with some chars in ISO-8859-1. Still looking for an effective and workable solution. I know so many countries in Africa have this same problem.

Comment: @Frank I see. But why are you focusing on ISO-8859-1 with this? It's a mainly european character set, which usually makes it unusable in other parts of the world. Would UTF-8 not be the superior choice by far? What native language(s) are you referring to? I think most of the world's alphabets are covered by Unicode in some way or other

Comment: Getting them to type it with no knowledge of scripting or some sort is the challenge and a real nightmare.

Comment: @Frank can you make a concrete example of what needs to be typed on what kind of keyboard layout?

Comment: See above of an example. It can only convert in the question section and doesn't convert in the comment section. the above is - &#193;nam &#224;b&#236;a &#232;b&#232;a &#211;gbu&#225;

Comment: @Frank but does your keyboard not have the backtick ` ? If I type backtick and then `A`, I get `À`. If I type `´` and then `A`, I get `Á`, no additional tools needed. Does that not work on your system? What operating system are you on?

Comment: I have and tried it see here testing UTF-8 `A `c `C - It doesn't work. I am using a windows server 2003 OS but I am typing into a textarea (php app)

Comment: @Frank it doesn't work for `C`, but should at least for vowels. Strange! But in that case, maybe you want to work programmatically: If you see `´` followed by `A` in the text, convert it to `Á` automatically. In PHP, that would be `str_replace("´A", "Á", $string);` that might be the easiest way.

Comment: I have the backtick but can not find the fronttick on my keyboard. Can see you used it above where can I get that? Do I need to do str_replace for all of them or is there an array() or something?

Comment: @Pekka kindly see my answer below if it makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: @Frank re the front tick, I have that underneath the backtick key on my layout. If it's not visible on your keyboard, it probably doesn't have it! Although it's odd - I'd have thought that's a standard character.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I have decided to do. Hope it puts somebody else on the right footing.
With Special thanks to @Pekka for the patience, guidance and support.

```
// Replaces combination char with special chars
$phrase  = "`U `are ^here tod`ay.";
$search = array("`U", "`a", "^h");
$replace   = array("&#251;", "&#241;", "&#224;");

$resulte = str_replace($search, $replace, $phrase);
```

Could be cleaner in a function though

Comment: I'd say this makes sense. Depending on your encoding, you should be able to use the actual character `á` instead of the HTML entity - you'd just have to make sure that the PHP file's encoding is in the same encoding as the data. But this looks solid, and probably is fairly easy to memorize for the users.